# Atom PHP lint not working Windows 10

Tags: php, atom-editor

I have fresh installation of Atom. Installed linter package and then linter-php.

In config.cson file i have following

```
"*":
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "c545e431-a953-b271-c123-c021c950953b"
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
  core: {}
  editor:
    invisibles: {}
    tabLength: 4
  linter: {}
  "linter-php":
    executablePath: "C:/php/"
```

I downloaded PHP zip from `http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.16-Win32-VC11-x86.zip` and extracted inside `C:/php`

Can any one help me out in fixing this. I don't find any thing i am missing.

**Update**

This is the error i am getting

```
Error: 'C:/php/' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
    at parameters.exit (C:\Users\Raheel\.atom\packages\linter-php\node_modules\atom-linter\lib\helpers.js:70:20)
    at triggerExitCallback (C:\Users\Raheel\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.2.4\resources\app.asar\src\buffered-process.js:213:47)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Raheel\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.2.4\resources\app.asar\src\buffered-process.js:235:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that php.exe is in c:\php and not in c:\php\php-5.6.16-Win32-VC11-x86?

Comment: yes i am sure. All the php files are directly inside C:/php

Comment: I updated question and placed screenshot of file file strucutre

Comment: Is your c:\php directory in the PATH system variable? what happens when you run php -l from the command line?

Comment: Reading the error message, what about if you put `executablePath: "C:/php/php.exe"`, or `executablePath: "C:\\php\\php.exe"` ? Sorry if i'm wrong, I I'm not usual with the tools you're talking about, but the error message is quite self-explanatory

Comment: I entered C:\php in my System Environment variables PATH already. However when i do php -l from command line i get error box

`"The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".`

Comment: @yolenoyer i treid both paths you mentioned. And upon saving config file i get this error `Unable to determine the version of "C:/php/php.exe", please verify that this is the right path to PHP`

Comment: you need the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio, see http://windows.php.net/

Comment: @dev0 I installed this component from `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679` and still on command line `php -l` i get the same error

Comment: @dev I installed 86 version and now php -l running fine

Comment: ok so the path is "C:\\php\php.exe" Worked

Answer (score 6):

I just went through the same thing. Here is my config.cson file. I'm using wamp for local PHP testing so my path will look different to the php.exe but the concept is the same.

```
"*":
  core:
  ...
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
  linter: {}
  "linter-php":
    executablePath: "C:/wamp/bin/php/php6.5.12/php.exe"
```

Hope this helps! (BTW the ... is just extra stuff in my config.cson file that wouldn't have helped)

Comment: It may be the 64 bit version too, but this worked for me too,
    executablePath: "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php6.5.12/php.exe"